# Getting error while installing Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am getting the below error when I run `rvm requirements` command.

Can someone please help with this? I tried couple of solutions but it did not work.

OS: MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

Error:

```
_$ rvm requirements
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system..........
Installing required packages: apple-gcc42..There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try brew tap --repair and make sure brew doctor looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation
.
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install apple-gcc42',
please read /Users//package_install_apple-gcc42.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1._
```

I have also tried to install the ruby directly and getting the below error:

```
$ rvm install 2.4.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.4.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
You requested building with '/bin/gcc-4.2' but it is not in your path.
```

Comment: Do you have a recent version of brew? Can you put the error log here...

Comment: What's is in the log files mentioned in the error messages? Have you tried the suggestions from the error message? What was the result?

Comment: Do you have XCode installed?

Comment: please run command `brew tap --repair`

Comment: `Try brew tap --repair and make sure brew doctor looks reasonable.`

Comment: Specifically, do you have command line tools installed? `xcode-select --install`.